# Intel 1U R1304BB4DC fails to boot

Tags: hardware

I own an Intel 1U R1304BB4DC server, with Windows Server 2013 on it. After installing latest Windows Updates I was forced to reboot it. Since then I am not able to boot to my OS + I get no output at all on a connected working monitor + no keyboard LEDs. It's worth mentioning that CPU coolers are working at max speed the entire time the server is powered up.

I have only one power supply connected to the server (it's been like this for ages, without any problem), so the only warning (orange) LED is the one indicating lack of one PSU.

Things I have tried so far:

```
- removed all RAM DIMMs, connected them one by one (and even two by two for dual-channel);
- removed all HDDs (4 SAS disks - RAID10) and powered on the server, nothing on the monitor;
```

I am planning to buy a new power supply to test it with the server. Are there any other things that I could test?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by buying two new PSUs.